# Real time serial data acquisition

Tags: pic

I wish to take the samples from pic16f877a,4Mhz HS( if it is given a sine wave input) and plot the same.I am giving 230vp sine wave 50hz as input and transformed it into 5v range and level shifted it into positive voltages.

This is my code

```
                    // Loop variable


  float val,val1;//Declare the adcvalue stored variables
  char uart_rd[50],uart_rd1[50];

  void rmsv();
  void adc_uart();//adc read and uart write
  void interrupt(){
    if (PIR1.ADIF) {
      PIR1.ADIF=0; // clear AD interrupt flag

          val= (ADRESH << 8) | ADRESL; // read dadta from channel 0
              {


         val1=(val*325.0)/1023.0;
          FloatToStr(val1,uart_rd1);
         strncpy(uart_rd,uart_rd1,3);
         UART1_Write_Text(uart_rd1);

         //UART1_Write(10);
        UART1_Write(13);
        delay_us(1);
      }

           Delay_Cyc(3); //wait acquisition time
      ADCON0.F2=1; //start conversion again
    }
         }
  void main()
  {
      TRISA=0XFF;//porta as input
  ADCON1 = 0x82; // AN0->AN4 selected as analog input
    ADCON0 = 0b11000001; // Configue analog mode
    INTCON.GIE = 1; //Enable global interrupt
    INTCON.PEIE = 1; //Enable peripheral interrupt
    PIE1.ADIE = 1; //Enable ADC interrupt
    Delay_us(20); //wait for acquisition time
    ADCON0.F2 = 1; //start conversion
      // ADCON1=0X81;
       UART1_Init(9600);               // Initialize UART module at 9600 bps
       //ADC_Init();


      while(1);

   }
```

I have checked the values in hyperterminal and see that the controller not even sample the peak voltage.I wish to have the samples correctly so that I can able to plot the waveform correctly

Comment: Have you tried using breakpoints the debugger?  Is the interrupt firing?  Is your adc read working correctly?  Also using a float for an ADC read is wrong, the adc produces a 16 bit int.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is not a software problem. You say "controller not even sample the peak voltage" and that the signal rage is between 5V and 0V. Well, if you have configured your PIC ADC using the PIC power voltage (Vp) as reference voltage and  if the power voltage is less than 5V ( Vp<5V), then your max adc Voltage range is Vp. It could cause that the peak of the sin signal after ADC acquisition looks cut.

```
    Vp    ________           _________           _________
                  \         /         \         /
                   \       /           \       /
                    \     /             \     / 
                     \   /               \   /
     0                \_/                 \_/
```

Measure the power voltage on the PIC pin and if it is the reason then adjust the voltage source or transform the signal into Vp range .